# Istanbul: generate code cobertura report with mocha

Tags: javascript, code-coverage, mocha.js, istanbul

I can't generate a cobertura report with Istanbul running my mocha tests.

```
istanbul report cobertura cover _mocha test
```

The report in cobertura-coverage.xml is empty.

Note that if I run without report option (`istanbul cover _mocha test`) everything works fine and I can see in the console the coverage summary.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I actually made it works splitting it into two commands `istanbul cover _mocha test; istanbul report cobertura` I'm not sure if there is a better way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `--`:

```
istanbul cover --report cobertura _mocha test
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work, the correct answer is http://stackoverflow.com/a/27287702/537815 as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 15):

Correct one is...

```
istanbul cover --report cobertura _mocha tests
```

Cover followed by `--report cobertura`

Answer (score 4):

For nyc its

```
nyc --reporter cobertura mocha test
```